# How to backup Mozilla Firefox layout configuration?

Tags: firefox

Mozilla Firefox doesn't save my browser layout when I login on other machine. How to export its configuration?

My customized firefox is this way:

[image]

If I login on firefox, my firefox will be this way (*I did wait to sync*):

[image]

As you see, the layout is totally different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All user configurations are stored at `~/.mozilla` . If you replace this folder by the one you already configured, your browser layout will be loaded.

I admit: it is a low optimized solution, the layout is saved somewhere inside `.mozilla` .

Answer (score 1):

Use the Firefox `sync` functionality... open preferences...

[image]

Comment: Sync doesnt store my browser layout.

Comment: @VitorAbella it stores open tabs. What else are you expecting to be carried over? Window size/placement... that won't happen... and how long does that take to set?

Comment: I updated the question. Now you can see what I mean.

Comment: @VitorAbella are you talking about the search bar? Otherwise, I don't see what's different - Sync can sync add-ons, so those icons will show up soon enough.

Comment: @muru Half of these icons are from my bookmarks. Only syncying doesnt put the bookmarks in the right place and neither save their name (in my case no name, only icon). The only way I found to sync the layout is copying all .mozila as is written on my answer.

Comment: @muru , I know that the layout is stored somewhere inside .mozilla , but backuping .mozilla did the job.

Comment: @VitorAbella that looks like the work of an add-on. How did you set it up that way?

Comment: @muru I posted here how I do it https://askubuntu.com/questions/944431/how-do-i-put-my-bookmark-toolbar-on-the-right-of-address-bar-on-firefox/944432#944432