# How do I put my bookmark toolbar on the right of address bar on firefox?

Tags: firefox

To save space on my screen, I would like to put my bookmark toolbar next to address bar like this:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the default a `Star|Clipboard` next to the address bar anyway?

Comment: @Ziazis Yes. The layout is personal choice. I like to see my bookmarks and save one click when accessing them ( i dont need to click in the star )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a gif to make it easier:
[image]